# After clicking on /profile i land to the path /login. How do i automatically land after completed login again on /profile?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with reactrouter. I am not logged in i click on the /profile link. Then i am forwarded to /login (Thats working fine). After successful login i am landing at home and not at /profile

```
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            authed ? 
            (<Component {...props}/>) 
            : 
            (
              <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/login',
                    state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
            )
        )}
    />
)

render() {
    const loggedIn = this.props.isLoggedIn;

    return(
        <Switch>

        <Route exact path="/" component={ UserPanel } />
        <Route exact path="/confirm" component={ EmailConfirmation } />

        {/* <Route exact path="/admin" component={ AdminPanel } /> */}
        <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => ( loggedIn
            ? <Redirect to='/' />
            : <Login/>
          )} />

          <PrivateRoute path='/admin' component={AdminPanel} authed = {this.props.admin}/>
        <PrivateRoute path='/createevent' component={CreateEvent} authed = {loggedIn}/>
        <PrivateRoute path='/profile' component={Profile} authed = {loggedIn}/>
        </Switch>

    )
}
```

Comment: RE: `After successful login i am landing at home` What is "home", your `AdminPanel`?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Home is "UserPanel". Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems like you have already set a state on the `Redirect` on a private route with:

```
<Redirect to={{
  pathname: '/login',
  state: { from: props.location }
}}
/>
```

Now, you can utilise this state on your Login component to redirect the user right back to where he came from. Borrowing a Login component from [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow):

```
function LoginPage() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  let login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      history.replace(from);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
      <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The state from location is extracted to a variable `from` or if it does not exist (user came to the route on his own volition, entering the URL or clicking a button) sets it to `/` by default.

Later on successful authentication, user is redirected to `from`.

Comment: this is for functional components. I am using a class component. So this way doesn`t work

Comment: @sand24ro You don't know how to translate this to class components?

Comment: i found a solution around. I used redux to store it in the state and give it to the redirect

Comment: @sand24ro that is not required, but okay